# Are the counters in the same word of the numbers?

Tags: spelling, counting

I don't understand if the counters are in the same word of the numbers, for example do I write 한개 or 한 개?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“한 개” is correct.

---

Most of units are 의존 명사 (translates to “dependent/bound noun”). And you space before them.

> ### Hangul orthography §5.2.42
>
> 의존 명사는 띄어 쓴다.
> You space before dependent/bound nouns (의존 명사).

And whether a unit is an 의존 명사 or not, you always space before units. This is *“recommended”* by [the standard](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/where-can-i-find-the-official-hangul-orthography-and-rules-on-pronunciations).

> ### Hangul orthography §5.2.43
>
> 단위를 나타내는 명사는 띄어 쓴다. You space before unit nouns.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So the counter's inital is red with a "c" sound like in the word "cat", right?

Comment: @EmaTavox If that’s an English question, yes, /k/ as in “cat.” If that’s supposed to be something else, I’m afraid I couldn’t get that.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you, now it's completely clear.

Comment: can you please add a link to this?

Comment: @user17915 Here it is. https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/where-can-i-find-the-official-hangul-orthography-and-rules-on-pronunciations