# Where can I find the official “Hangul orthography” and “rules on pronunciations?”

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

Where can I find the official “[*Hangul orthography*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_orthography) and [*rules on pronunciations*](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%91%9C%EC%A4%80%EC%96%B4_%EA%B7%9C%EC%A0%95)?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Hangul orthography*

***Hangul orthography***, *Ministry of Culture, Sports and Tourism*, public notice #2017-12 (effective from March 28, 2017.). [Here](https://kornorms.korean.go.kr/m/m_regltn.do#a262).

### A booklet PDF that explains (in Korean) the both

**There’s a good *official* booklet that explains them all and answers quite a lot of questions on Korean language Stack Exchange.** For orthography and pronunciation<sub>(not at the phonological level though)</sub>, it’s *the greatest* learning material of all, if you can read Korean. It’s a bunch of standard rules anyways.

Well, the problem is, **[the official website](https://kornorms.korean.go.kr) is clunky and frustratingly unfriendly to users.** There’s no [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) links to them. In other words, they don’t have unique URLs bound to resources that I’m afraid I can’t tell you the link for you to simply type in and get. They only allow you to browse their website through [`POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) requests.

[image: Their website]

If you’re Linux-savvy, you can use this command to download it.

```
curl \
    --data 'upload_file_path=refr&upload_file_name=5f99e023-dbbe-4975-9db0-b4355eabd06b_0&upload_file_original_name=_' \
    --request POST \
    --output 'Official Hangul orthography, rules on pronunciation, and explanation on them (2018).pdf' \
    https://kornorms.korean.go.kr/common/download.do
```

[image: Index]
[image: The cover of the booklet]
[image: Preview #1]
[image: Preview #2]